# Sitecore Hidden Items

Tags: .net, logging, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

Every morning when i try to login in my local sitecore login page, i almost have to wait for 5-6 minutes. When i opened the sitecore log files, i found bunch of debug lines similar to this "ManagedPoolThread #8 07:51:29 DEBUG Could not find a language mapping for source language id '{3C5919DF-1131-4B94-A96D-685C432CA586}' - skipping". The weird thing is when i search for that guid value, i can find the item however i don't see the item in the content tree by default. It's like the item is there but somehow it's hidden or content tree doesn't know the item exists. The guid value is for the language file, which i am not using in the project and can get rid of. Is there anyway to display all the items like this, which are there but hidden somehow from the content tree and delete them all?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you have all the languages installed on your local instance. Is it possible that you have a just English as a language and other language that the website uses are missing from your local instance?

Comment: Looking at the debug log, there no template mapping found by Sitecore and it ends up finding the item in cache. But afterwards, struggles to get the item for that specific language. Check that the template exists or not for that item in the Master DB?

Comment: is there anyway to get rid from cache too, since i can't find the template from master DB?

Comment: You could try this and see if it works - Go to http://<sitename>/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx and click on "Clear All".

Comment: tried that still didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that items are stored in item bucket?
If so, just check 'Buckets' check mark in View Tab.
This was the case in my situation.
[Read further here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/managing%20items/item%20buckets)

Answer (score 0):

To see hidden items goto view tab in the ribbon and check "Hidden Items" checkbox

Comment: it is but i still don't see those items in content tree. If i search by guid id i do see the item.